# Login process after course choise

Tags: users, redirection

I have a website where visitors can follow a course. I have several course available. I have problems to achieve the following process:

A anonymous visitor can see a list with available courses and can click on subscribe. The subscribe link is a Rule_link names Subscribe and belongs to the course module.

If the users is already logged or authorised no problem. By the subscribe rule link I am able to do all.

If user are anonymous they should make an account. In this process I will lose the subscribion to the specific course.

How to solve this?